# LAG Function to take only the previous date than running in exact sequence

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a requirement to find the customer's previous visit date in a store from the visit date.

```
SELECT 
   CUSTOMER, 
   STORE, 
   VISIT_DATE, 
   LAG(VISIT_DATE) 
      OVER (partition by CUSTOMER ORDER BY CUSTOMER_CODE,VISIT_DATE ASC ) 
   PREVIOUS_VISIT_DATE, 
   DATEDIFF(d,
      LAG(VISIT_DATE) 
         OVER (partition by CUSTOMER ORDER BY CUSTOMER_CODE,VISIT_DATE ASC),
      VISIT_DATE) DAYDIFFERENCE
FROM CUSTOMER_DETAILS;
```

[Current Output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iul9P.png

| Customer | Visit Date | PreviousVisitDate | DayDifference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 05-01-2020 | NULL | 0 |
| jack | 06-01-2020 | 05-01-2020 | 1 |
| jack | 07-01-2020 | 06-01-2020 | 1 |
| jack | 07-01-2020 | 07-01-2020 | 1 |
| jack | 08-01-2020 | 07-01-2020 | 1 |
| jack | 09-01-2020 | 08-01-2020 | 1 |
| jack | 09-01-2020 | 09-01-2020 | 1 |

[Expected Output][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL2lN.png

```
| Customer |  Visit Date | PreviousVisitDate | DayDifference|
|:---------|:-----------:|:-----------------:|-------------:|
|Jack |  05-01-2020 | NULL       | 0|
|jack |  06-01-2020 | 05-01-2020 | 1|   
|jack |  07-01-2020 | 06-01-2020 | 1|   
|jack |  07-01-2020 | 06-01-2020 | 1|   
|jack |  08-01-2020 | 07-01-2020 | 1|
|jack |  09-01-2020 | 08-01-2020 | 1|
|jack |  09-01-2020 | 08-01-2020 | 1|
--------------------------------------
```

The previous visit date is appearing as it is in sequence but i do want the exact previous day. how can it be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The Previous day regardless of whether the customer visited then? Or the previous_visit_date?

Comment: It should be Previous Visit date,

Comment: In your ORDER BY why are you including CUSTOMER_CODE? See Kazi's comment above.

Comment: CUSTOMER_CODE was a typo error. But my requirement is not met still. The Previous Visit date should be exactly the previous visit date, even if visit date repeats

Comment: It sounds like you may need to GROUP BY user and visit_day ORDER BY visit_day. For every group combination you would then have only one prior visit_day.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CUSTOMER, 
STORE, 
VISIT_DATE, 
LAG(VISIT_DATE) OVER (partition by CUSTOMER ORDER BY VISIT_DATE ASC ) PREVIOUS_VISIT_DATE,
DATEDIFF(d,LAG(VISIT_DATE) OVER (partition by CUSTOMER ORDER BY VISIT_DATE ASC),VISIT_DATE) DAYDIFFERENCE
FROM CUSTOMER_DETAILS;
```

To get last visit_date smaller than current row VISIT_DATE:

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER,     
    VISIT_DATE,     
    (select max (visit_date) from CUSTOMER_DETAILS  C WHERE C.visit_date<CD.visit_date)PREVIOUS_VISIT_DATE,
    DATEDIFF(d,(select max (visit_date) from CUSTOMER_DETAILS  C WHERE C.visit_date<CD.visit_date),VISIT_DATE) DAYDIFFERENCE    
    FROM CUSTOMER_DETAILS cd
```

Output:

```
    | CUSTOMER | VISIT_DATE |PREVIOUS_VISIT_DATE|DAYDIFFERENCE|
    |----------|------------|-------------------|-------------|
    | Jack     | 2020-05-01 | NULL              | NULL        |
    | jack     | 2020-06-01 | 2020-05-01        | 31          |
    | jack     | 2020-07-01 | 2020-06-01        | 30          |
    | jack     | 2020-08-01 | 2020-07-01        | 31          |
    | jack     | 2020-09-01 | 2020-08-01        | 31          |
    | jack     | 2020-09-01 | 2020-08-01        | 31          |
```

Comment: CUSTOMER_CODE was a typo error. But my requirement is not met  still.   The Previous Visit date should be exactly the previous visit date, even if visit date repeats

Comment: I have revised my answer. Please check.

Comment: @Lionel please let me know if you face any more difficulties with this query: